# Are there any known special properties of a number located between twin primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

With the exception of $4$, every number located between twin primes is divisible by $6$.

This one is obvious, but are there any other properties that can be ascribed to such numbers?

A property may be ascribed either to each number individually or to the entire sequence.

For example, consider the amount of prime factors of such numbers:

- Is there any known restriction on this amount per each number?
- Is there any known restriction on this amount as a function of the sequence-index?

---

The context in which I am asking this question:

What attempts have been made towards proving that there are infinitely many pairs of twin primes, by proving that there are infinitely many numbers located between twin primes?

Comment: FYI : Average of twin prime pairs ([OEIS : A014574](http://oeis.org/A014574))

Comment: @mathlove: There are some interesting properties there, and perhaps even more interesting is the fact that they have been determined relatively recently. Thanks.

Comment: [Maybe useful](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/36154/average-of-twin-prime-pairs-is-abundant-number-except-for-4-and-6-any-prime-is)

Comment: @Elaqqad: Thank you, but the answer to this question shows that it implies nothing more than these numbers being divisible by $6$ (which as I've mentioned, is obvious). Thanks anyway.

Comment: @barak manos, just in case, I asked a related question about twin primes, it might give you another point of view, it is about twin primes in the vicinity of twin primes. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005852/test-total-number-of-twin-primes-in-the-vicinity-of-twin-primes-how-can-i-calc

Answer (score 8):

About the sequence you're after, I would say that it is possibly more interesting to consider the quotients when they're divided by 6. The result is the [OEIS sequence A002822](https://oeis.org/A002822).

I'm not sure whether this counts as "special", but there seems to be a way to associate bijectively A002822 to the twin prime pairs. I actually found a few pointers in other questions here, so you could simply check them. In [Does proving the following statement equate to proving the twin prime conjecture?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698021/does-proving-the-following-statement-equate-to-proving-the-twin-prime-conjecture) you can find a pointer to an arXiv paper from 2011, and in [About a paper by Gold & Tucker (characterizing twin primes)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798358/about-a-paper-by-gold-tucker-characterizing-twin-primes) you will find a link to a small, 20 years older article which also proves the same bijective relationship and derives a similar formula (even if it's hard to distinguish because of their $G(n)$ function).

My preferred formulation of the theorem is as follows:

> *Any twin prime pair greater than $(3;5)$ is of the form $(6z-1;6z+1)$ where $z\inℕ$ and satisfies following system of inequalities:
> $$6xy+5x+5y+4 \neq z$$ $$6xy+7x+5y+6 \neq z$$ $$6xy+7x+7y+8 \neq z$$
> for all $(x,y) \in (\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\})^2$; and conversely, for any such integer $z$, the
> pair $(6z-1;6z+1)$ is a twin prime pair.*

In response to your contextual question, you can see above that a few people did try to find a proof using this theorem. And there are regularly similar attempts posted on the arXiv. For the sake of citing an example, I'll mention this one: [Twin Prime Sieve](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5240).

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer!

Comment: they are Also the only numbers not describable in one of the forms  :  $6kl+k+l, 6kl-k-l , 6kl+k-l$  for aome $k,l$ where both are positive integers ...